# Why is Google Play Services version in Android SDK Manager different from the version required in gradle file?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I checked the Google Play Services version in SDK manager and it showed me 25. But the versions required in gradle file follow an entirely different pattern. Only by trial and error I could figure out that it should be 7.5.0. How can I map the version in SDK manager to the version I need for build.gradle? Is there any other way of figuring it out?

Screenshots provided below:

Google Play Services version in Android SDK Manager - 25

[image: Google Play Services version in Android SDK Manager - 25]

Google Play Services version required in build.gradle - 7.5.0

[image: Google Play Services version required in build.gradle - 7.5.0]

Comment: gradle is like a online repository from where you can add libraries to your project if its not there in sdk or external libraries, so it can be different.

Comment: just use a latest play-services via project-structure/your app module/dependencies/add library dependency and type there in search "play-services". If you can download picked version via sdk manager you will be asked by android studio.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases just follow updates here.

Revision and version is a bit different things. *From my understanding* - revision is just the sequential number of the release.
The actual version of Google Play Service is 7.8. It is revision 26.

If you update your Gradle file, Android Studio will prompt you to download the latest revision of Google Play Services.